# Java task: Implement method for converting number to other numeration system

Tags: java

The condition of my task:

> Implement the logic of the method `convertNumberToOtherNumerationSystem()`, which should convert numbers `number.getDigit()` from one number system(numerationSystem) to another (expectedNumerationSystem).
>
> throw `NumberFormatException` if the number of incorrect, for example: number "120" with number system "2".
>
> Validation for `number.getDigit()` - a positive integer.

And this is my code:

Class Solution

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number number = new Number(NumerationSystemType._10, "6");
        Number result = convertNumberToOtherNumerationSystem(number, NumerationSystemType._2);
        System.out.println(result);    //expected 110
    }

    public static Number convertNumberToOtherNumerationSystem(Number number, NumerationSystem expectedNumerationSystem) {
        return null;
    }
```

Enum NumerationSystemType

```
public enum NumerationSystemType implements NumerationSystem {
    _16,
    _12,
    _10,
    _9,
    _8,
    _7,
    _6,
    _5,
    _4,
    _3,
    _2;

    @Override
    public int getNumerationSystemIntValue() {
        return Integer.parseInt(this.name().substring(1));
    }
}
```

class Number

```
public class Number {
    private NumerationSystem numerationSystem;
    private String digit;

    public Number(NumerationSystem numerationSystem, String digit) {
        this.numerationSystem = numerationSystem;
        this.digit = digit;
    }

    public NumerationSystem getNumerationSystem() {
        return numerationSystem;
    }

    public String getDigit() {
        return digit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Number{" +
            "numerationSystem=" + numerationSystem +
            ", digit='" + digit + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
```

Interface NumerationSystem

```
public interface NumerationSystem {
    int getNumerationSystemIntValue();
}
```

I shall be grateful for any help and any advice.

Comment: You've posted requirements and *unexplained* code but no question. What is the problem with your current code? How is it not behaving properly? What specifically are you confused about? Please help us, since if you don't ask a specific question, we can't give a specific answer. Please go through the [tour] and the [help] and in particular the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections.

Comment: Well, I read that link you gave.
Sorry for not exact question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the numeration system of the source number to parse the digits, then use the expected numeration system to generate the new digits.

```
public static Number convertNumberToOtherNumerationSystem(Number number, NumerationSystem expectedNumerationSystem) {
    // Get an Integer using the numeration system to parse the digits.
    int value = Integer.parseInt(number.getDigit(), number.getNumerationSystem().getNumerationSystemIntValue());
    // Convert it to new form.
    return new Number(expectedNumerationSystem, Integer.toString(value, expectedNumerationSystem.getNumerationSystemIntValue()));
}
```

This does indeed produce `110` - well actually it prints *Number{numerationSystem=_2, digit='110'}*.